# how to check empty or !empty field

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php $j=0; 
      while ($j<2){ if(empty($recent['id'][$k])) break;?>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-7" style="padding:0px;">
       <div class="img-sm">
         <?php if(!empty($recent['image'][$k])) { ?>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url().url_thumb($recent['image'][$k],'konsultasi/') ?>" />
         <?php } else { ?>
           <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php base_url().'assets/images/logo.png' ?>" />
         <?php } ?>
       </div>

    </div>
<?php $j++; $k++; } ?>
```

The Problem is, if empty image its not working to me.

Comment: Can you post your `$recent` array

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($recent)`.

Comment: I will assume what is being checked !empty is not an array, doesnt exist. Try use a combination of 'isset()' and '!= NULL'

Comment: this is it array(4) { ["id"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" } ["image"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(69) "assets/images/uploads/konsultasi/010df4f05a905f167421ecda7fd1fdd0.jpg" [1]=> string(69) "assets/images/uploads/konsultasi/da573b42cfd55cb8df80500bb866bef5.jpg" } ["title"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "test lagi" [1]=> string(18) "testing konsultasi" } ["date"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "Jul,14 2015" [1]=> string(11) "Jul,13 2015" } }

Answer (score 1):

From the [empty function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Returns **FALSE** if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns **TRUE**.
>   The following things are considered to be empty:
>   • "" (an empty string)
>   • 0 (0 as an integer)
>   • 0.0 (0 as a float)
>   • "0" (0 as a string)
>   • NULL
>   • FALSE
>   • array() (an empty array)
>   • $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Simply your `$recent['image'][$k]` does not match the above cases where `empty()` returns `FALSE`.

Maybe your string has blanks charactes inside. Try to use:

`if (empty(trim($recent['image'][$k])))`

Answer (score -1):

You have not declared you k variable before the while loop.

Add: ***$k = 0;***

I would do this however:

```
<?php

//Init loop var
$i = 0;

//Loop over results
while($i < 2){

   //Skip loop if no id found
   if(empty($recent['id'][$i]) continue;

   //Output containers
   echo '<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-7" style="padding:0px;">';
   echo '<div class="img-sm">';

   //Check has image, output dependent
   if(!empty($recent['image'][$i])){
       echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url().url_thumb($recent['image'][$i],'konsultasi/') ?>" />';
   }
   else{
       echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php base_url().'assets/images/logo.png' ?>" />';
   }

   //Close containers
   echo '</div></div>';

   //Increment counter
   $i++;

}

?>
```

EDIT: maybe keep your way of output, using the browser rather than php (was too lazy to do that in this editor). But notice im only using the one counter variable to try and save confusion.